# How many ring homomorphism are there from $\mathbb{Z} / 12\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z} / 20\mathbb{Z}$? Find the image and kernel of them.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

> How many ring homomorphism are there from $\mathbb{Z} / 12\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z} / 20\mathbb{Z}$? Find the image and kernel of them.

The above is the question, this is my attempt at an answer,

"Let a homomorphism $f$ map $\mathbb{Z} / 12\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z} / 20\mathbb{Z}$. Then $f(1) = n$, and $f(t)=nt$ mod 20 $\forall t \in \mathbb{Z} / 12\mathbb{Z}$. This is well defined if $f(12u)= 0$ $\forall u \in \mathbb{Z}$, ie. provided $12un = 0$ mod 20. Hence n is even.

Then the homomorphism is $f(t)= 2mt$ mod 20 for some integer m and is well defined.

Thus for some s and t,:
$f(s + t) - f(s) - f(t) = 2m(s+t) - 2ms - 2mt = 0$
Also,
$f(st) - f(s)f(t) = 2mst - (2ms)(2mt) = st(2m - 4m^2) = 0$
so $2m = 4m^2$ mod 20.
$2m - 4m^2 = 20p$ for some $p$. 
$m - 2m^2 = 10p$
$2m^2 - m = 0$ mod 10.
Let $h(m) = 2m^2 - m$ mod 10

$h(0) = 0, h(1) = 1, h(2) = 6, h(3) = 5, h(4) = 8, h(5) = 5, h(6) =6, h(7)=1, h(8)=0, h(9) = 3$.

So $m = 0$ or $m = 8.$ Hence we have two ring homomorphisms q and r from $\mathbb{Z} / 12\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z} / 20\mathbb{Z}$, namely;
. $q(t) = 0$ mod 20 $\forall t \in \mathbb{Z} / 12\mathbb{Z}$ with image ${0}$ in $\mathbb{Z} / 20\mathbb{Z}$, and kernel $\mathbb{Z} / 12\mathbb{Z}$
. $r(t) = 16t$ mod 20 $\forall t \in \mathbb{Z} / 12\mathbb{Z}$ with image {0,16} in $ \mathbb{Z} / 20\mathbb{Z}$ and kernel ${0, 5, 10}$ in $\mathbb{Z} / 12\mathbb{Z}$"

I found this question confusing since I have only done this type of question with numbers that are multiples of each other, such as $\mathbb{Z} / 12\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z} / 6\mathbb{Z}$. Meaning that I tried to follow the system I used for such questions, but think it just ended up a mess, can someone show me where I have gone right/wrong.

Comment: So you do not require your ring homomorphisms to preserve $1$?

Comment: I suppose yes, we would need f(1) = 1, in which case all my working from there on is wrong?

Comment: If you do require it, there will be no homomorphisms at all.

Comment: Having thought over it, maybe then I do not require it, because surely a similar argument could show there are no homomorphisms between z/6z and z/12z? (when there are)

Comment: From $12un\equiv 0 \mod 20$ it follows $3un\equiv 0 \mod 5$, so  $n\equiv 0 \mod 5$. Why do you mean that $n$ is even?

Comment: I put n even since it's multiplied by 12,I thought being able to write it in that format would make calculations simpler. Can you please explain the implications of your calculations?

Comment: Since $12n\equiv\mod 20$ then $12n=20m$ for some $m$. Hence $3n=5m$ and $5$ divides $n$.