# Ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$

Tags: ring-theory

How many ring homomorphisms are there from $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z/20\mathbb Z$?

In all cases, describe
the image and kernel of the homomorphism.

I am not even sure how to proceed on counting how many homomorphism are there any help appreciated.

Comment: Just write down all maps (note that both rings are finite, so there are only finitely many) and check which ones are ring homomorphisms :>

Comment: @Laters yeah, that should only take about 10 megaseconds with a decent program.

Comment: You won't even need to try all the possibilities.  Just try to map $1\in \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ to  $1\in \mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$ and see why that cannot work.  Then try mapping it to $5\in \mathbb{Z}/20\mathbb{Z}$.  You'll see the pattern.

Comment: Actually an exact duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/528283/29335 , which unfortunately had no answers. Please use the search feature before you ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ring homomorphism sends $1$ to $1$ (if you live in a just world.) So $12$ should go to $12$, but $12=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ and not in $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$.